# Upload multiple files in Django admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Django: 3.0.6

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):

    image_42_webp_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=_get_upload_to,
                                           validators=[validate_image,],
                                           blank=True,
                                           verbose_name="42 webp 1х")

    image_42_fallback_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=_get_upload_to,
                                      validators=[validate_image,],
                                      blank=True,
                                      verbose_name="42 1х")

    image_42_webp_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to=_get_upload_to,
                                           validators=[validate_image,],
                                           blank=True,
                                           verbose_name="42 webp 2х")
    <...>
```

There are much more image fields in the model. As a matter of fact more than 50. Why do I need them is another question. But in short every image is adjusted manually for better site performance.

Anyway, there are a lot of image fields and I wouldn't like to overburden the admin by loading so many files one at a time.

I'd like to use something for bulk upload. I have failed to find a ready made app. So, if you suggest me some app, that would be great.

If not, well, any solution would suit.

Maybe this can be somehow used?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files

In model admin the template 'includes/fieldset.html' is responsible for creating/editing new model instance.

What I need is just some means not fill the fields by hand.

[image]

Any means, even Selenium would suit. Or maybe a raw http post request (though login is required and CSRF protection is switched on).

What can I try here?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like AWS serverless lambda connected to S3 bucket?
You hold an empty S3 bucket (an empty folder with no files).
The minute you upload files to you bucket the the Lambda gets an event trigger and starts working with a simple python api requests script would start working and would upload the files from s3 by order system/method you would give (say the names of files would be the nae one the field in model or some sort of ordering).